# Installing Ubuntu on 32bit XP system for the first time

Tags: installation, windows-xp

Should Windows updates be completed before installing Ubuntu?

Should the anti-virus and/or the firewall be stopped while installing?

What is the exact procedure?

Comment: Are you using WUBI as installation type.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using the Windows installer:

- Always a good idea to get all security updates
- You may want to temporarily disable your antivirus (but be sure to turn back on once Wubi is installed!)
- You can leave the firewall as is.

Comment: But ONLY if you're installing Ubuntu inside of Windows should you do this.  Except the "get all security updates" part... do that all the time :P